# how can I define string arrays to a activity title at java?

Tags: java, android

I am new on java. I am creating android application. I have create list menu based on a tutorial. The menu names comes from class name(MainActivity) however I would like to add title for each activity and show that text not activity name on list. please see my code. there is no layout. Thanks

package com.x.xname;

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes [] = {"MainActivity", "example1", "example2",
            "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"}; // add class name(MainActivity) to active second menu


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String tikla = classes [position];
        try{
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.x.xname." + tikla);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, can you provide an example of what is happening and what you want to happen?  Screenshots perhaps?

Comment: This is list menu code on android application. and strings have java classes.I mean "MainActivity" is my java class. When I change "MainActivity" string to another text the application is not working and I receive error message. I think is could not find which classes is need to go. Did I clear now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Apologies.. Java is not my native language.**

From looking at the code you have posted, the `onListItemClick` will take corresponding string from the array and try and find a class named whatever that string is which it then assumes is an `Activity`.

Instead of an array of string, have an array of a new class called "MenuOption" which contains a property for title and another for classname.

```
class MenuOption {
    public String title;
    public String className;

    public MenuOption(String title, String className)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.className = className;
    }
}
```

Your code would look like this..

```
MenuOption classes [] = { new MenuOption("My Main Activity Title", "MainActivity"), new MenuOption("Another Activity Title", "AnotherActivity")
```

Then change the click handler to something like this...

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    MenuItem tikla = classes [position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.x.xname." + tikla.className);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You may need to also change the layout file as well but you have not posted code for that so I cannot help further.

Comment: Thanks for response, yes you right. I would like to show title not classes name. I dont have a layout for this class. Is there another way to dot change current code and activity title.

Comment: Yes you do have a layout file.. android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 - Im sorry but I can't help you any further unless you reword your question.

Comment: I solve my problem by using replace 
tikla = tikla.replace("Title Name", "MainActivity"); 
Thank you for your Help :)

Comment: Thats not going to work.. without the changes I have mentioned you are only going to be able to have 1 activity available in the menu.

Comment: Sorry I implement that code to my code not yours.

Comment: If my answer has helped you achieve what you were looking to do it is customary to either accept the answer or 'up vote' the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put in classes the name of the classes of your app.. The intent needs the name of the class you want to launch as second parameter..

But it's unclear what you're asking..